# adjective for "not known to be needed"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an adjective or shortish expression for an item that is "not known to be needed".

Context:  at the beginning of a process, all items are "unknown as to whether they will be needed or not", so all items are "X". As I progress through my process, at any point in time I may realize that some item is now or will be needed for sure. At that point, the item moves from "X" to "needed".

Chat gives "discretionary" :) , good but not quite...

Comment: Can you give an example of how it would be used in a sentence?

Comment: @Barmar Can't give you a single sentence; it would be too complicated.  Let me try with a paragraph:

Here I am starting a process, and have a number of tools, which may turn out I will need or not.  At the beginning of my process, all are "unknown whether they will be needed or not", so all tools are "not X".  As I progress through my process, at any point in time I may realize that some tool Y is now or will be needed for sure.  At that point, Y moves from "not X" to "X".  At the end of the process, some tools are "X", and all the others, are known to be "not needed".

Comment: You've already explained what X is. You still haven't shown how it would be used in a sentence. Something like "Do we have all the X tools?"

Comment: @Barmar but I did... I gave you 3 sentences in the above paragraph, that contain X.

Comment: @Barmar OK fine, if you want: this widget is X, and that widget over there, is not X.

Comment: @Barmar no, can't say "Do we have all the X tools" - that would fit X=needed  .  But that's not what I want...  at the beginning of the process, I don't know if any tool will be needed or not.

Comment: Maybe what you mean is “potential.”

Comment: Why not 'possibly needed' / 'may be required'?

Comment: Or several variants on "unsorted", "unprocessed", "unscrutinised", etc, depending on what process is actually occurring (if you're going through a list judging if they're too expensive, that would be different from if you were judging if they were useless or too dangerous to take/use).

Comment: You've completely reversed the question when you added "not" in an edit. This invalidates the answers that were posted before the edit.

Comment: I would like to downvote this question but since you're new, the website tells me to treat you with kid gloves.  Why would you think there's a word with the specific meaning "not known to be needed"?  Why would there be such a word, and separate words for every other unknown status under the sun, "not known to be edible", and "not known to be required", "not known to be sufficient"???  The problem with all such questions (and there are many here) is that the questioner starts with a rudimentary sentence, X is Y, instead of  "the x of y is _______", and that structure paints you into a corner.

Comment: Are you trying/testing the tools as you come upon problems? Or are you encountering problems and then have in mind which tools you will need?

Answer (score 1):

**Indeterminate**. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indeterminate):

> 1b: not known in advance

If I understand correctly, your items or tools exist in three states: dispensability, indispensability, and indeterminate dispensability.

To insert my suggested answer into a paraphrase of your paragraph:

Here I am, starting a process and having a number of items, of which some I will need and some I will not. At the beginning of my process, the dispensability of all the items is indeterminate, that is, all items are indeterminately dispensable. (The adverb phrase might help to clarify that the indeterminacy applies to the items' state of dispensability). As I progress through my process, at any point in time I may realize that one of the items is needed. At that point, the item is no longer considered indeterminate or indeterminately dispensable but indispensable. At the end of the process, all items are unequivocally known to be either dispensable or indispensable, and no items are indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I would suggest **available**: from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/available) -

> 1: present or ready for immediate use

At the start of the process, all the items are "available" (present and ready for use) - at the end of it, some of them will have been assessed as "needed".

Answer (score 0):

Your "example sentence" (a prerequisite for single-word-requests, BTW) was **all items are "X"** (at the outset of your process) and you define X as *unknown as to whether they will be needed or not*. The statement "The item is unknown as to whether it will be needed" is like saying "The food is unknown as to whether it is poisonous".  That's not how natural language works. It's not idiomatic, and **food** makes a very poor subject for that sentence.

For it isn't the items themselves, but their status, that is unknown at the outset of the process. Yet you  want to force **items** to be the subject of your predicate, and that is where you're going wrong, IMO. (I taught freshman English classes at a good university for 5 years and have seen very intelligent students paint themselves into a corner like that many times.)

That fact that their status is unknown can be expressed in English:

> Whether items are needed is not known at this stage in the process.
>
> Whether items are needed is **to be determined**.
>
> Whether an item is needed is not known at this stage in the process.
>
> Whether an item is needed is **to be determined**.

And now you're trying to collapse the sentence into a single word or phrase, as though you had a dropdown list called **status** and were looking to populate it with choices.

```
Status:
to be determined
needed
unneeded
```

But you can't make "item" the label for your dropdown unless you include "status" in the value:

```
Item:
needed-status to be determined
needed
not needed
```

and you're looking for a more "elegant" way (in your view an adjective) that would express the idea "needed-status to be determined".

But that will take you down a dead-end street (since there's no English word with the meaning "needed-status to be determined"). Just make "status" the label (i.e. make status the subject of your sentence) and things will fall into place.

If you were creating a property or attribute of an Item object, you might name the property *IsNeeded*, and then you could have the following values:

```
IsNeeded:
yes
no
to be determined
```

That label, *IsNeeded*, corresponds to natural language "Whether it is needed....".

Answer (score -1):

Preexisting. For example, "unknown if object has a preexisting condition," or, "due to the preexisting nature of object, no further action is required."

Hope this helps.

Edit: Alternatively, Prerequisite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).